# VBA Copy and Paste Between Template Worksheet and Variable Worksheet

Tags: excel, variables, random, macros, vba

I've edited this post to show that I have done some research on this. Some of the code below was captured during a "Record Macro" session. I just can't figure out how to change the workbook names that it records into variables. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to copy and paste some data between two worksheets. One is a template and will always have the same name and the other varies depending on which one I open. The code I have now keeps throwing up an error. My current code is below! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I would like to manualy open the random workbook store it's name in a variable. Then have the macro open the template file, create a new tab(called neededInfo) in the templateFile, switch back to the manually opened file, select range("A1:B4"), then copy that to the new sheet in the templateFile. Let me know if there is a better way! I'm super new to this!

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim templateFile As Workbook ' template macro workbook; will always have same filename
Dim workingFile As String ' current working CSCC Quote download
Dim workingSheet As Worksheet ' only sheet in CSCC Quote
Dim tempSheet As Worksheet ' created sheet in CSCC Quote to hold temp data
Dim fileName As String
Dim wrkBook As Workbook
Dim nRow As Long
Dim neededInfo As Long
Dim neededRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set template file name
Set templateFile = "20161115 SMARTnet Template.xlsx"

Set templateFile = ActiveWorkbook
templateFile.Active
Set tempSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
tempSheet.Name = "neededInfo"
workingFile = ActiveSheet.Name
Range("A1:B4").Select
Selection.Copy
templateSheet.Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
workingFile.Activate

End Sub
```

My Solution:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim tPlate As Workbook ' template macro
Dim wrkngFile As Workbook ' current working CSCC Quote download
Dim wrkngSheet As Worksheet ' only sheet in CSCC Quote
Dim tSheet As Worksheet ' created sheet in template file to hold temp data
Dim fileName As String
Dim tPath As String, tFile As String ' template path location and template file
Dim nRow As Long
Dim neededInfo As Long
Dim neededRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

tPath = "C:\Users\tcoplien\Desktop\SMARTnet\"
tFile = tPath & "20161115 SMARTnet Template.xlsx"

Set wrkngFile = ActiveWorkbook
Range("A1:B4").Select
Selection.Copy

' Open template file and save name as variable
Set tPlate = Workbooks.Open(tFile)

Set tSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
tSheet.Name = "neededInfo"

tSheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wrkngFile.Activate
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: *keeps throwing up an error.*  What error, on what line?

Comment: *I would like to manualy open the random workbook store it's name in a variable. Then have the macro open the template file, create a new tab(called neededInfo) in the templateFile, switch back to the manually opened file, select range("A1:B4"), then copy that to the new sheet in the templateFile.* This seems like about 5 or 6 different problems, maybe try breaking it down and solving each individual step so it will not seem as overwhelming.

Comment: sorry about that! i suppose it would be nice to know where the error was. I got it fixed now, but thank you! and i believe the error was coming up at Set templateFile = ActiveWorkbook. I'll update it when i get a chance to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fairly close but there are a few issues. First, don't create a variable with its type as the name. Change `Dim workBook As Workbook` to something like `Dim bk As Workbook`.

Next you have the statement `Set templateFile = "20161115 SMARTnet Template.xlsx"`. This is effectively trying to set a workbook to a string. Instead change this to `Set templateFile = Workbooks("20161115 SMARTnet Template")`. Or better yet change this to:

```
Dim tempStr as String
tempStr = "20161115 SMARTnet Template"
Set templatefile = Workbooks(tempStr)
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the next few lines of code. It looks like you're adding a new tab to the `templatefile` workbook. Instead of activating the workbook, just use this `Set tempSheet = templatefile.Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)` and then rename this new sheet to "neededInfo".

Next, you set the `workingFile` variable to the active sheet which in this case will be the `neededInfo` sheet. I'm assuming that this isn't your intention. You will need to define the `workingSheet` variable before you add the new worksheet.

The new code could look something like this:

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim templatefile As Workbook
    Dim workingSheet As Worksheet ' only sheet in CSCC Quote
    Dim tempSheet As Worksheet ' created sheet in CSCC Quote to hold temp data
    Dim tempStr As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Set template file name
    tempStr = "20161115 SMARTnet Template"
    Set templatefile = Workbooks(tempStr)
    Set workingSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set tempSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)

    tempSheet.Name = "neededInfo"

    workingSheet.Range("A1:B4").Copy

    tempSheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I think this is what you were trying to accomplish. If not, this should be a good start for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I got a chance to look at again and figured it out. I'll post the solution that I got above! Yours worked too though so thank you!